# Update multiple rows with different values in a single SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with table `myTable` and columns `id, NameID, InvoiceNo, BilleeNo, Date`. The number of rows changes constantly (might increase or decrease).

myTable:

```
id    NameID   InvoiceNo    BilleeNo    Date
1     N01      4566         02          01-MAR-2013
2     N01      unallocated  02          01-MAR-2013
3     N02      1233         02          01-MAR-2013
4     N02      1233         02          01-MAR-2013
5     N02      unallocated  02          01-MAR-2013
6     N02      1244         02          01-JUN-2013
```

I want to update the unallocated `InvoiceNo` with a `InvoiceNo` which has same `NameID, BilleeNo` and `Date`.

The updated table would be :

```
id    NameID   InvoiceNo    BilleeNo    Date
1     N01      4566         02          01-MAR-2013
2     N01      4566         02          01-MAR-2013
3     N02      1233         02          01-MAR-2013
4     N02      1233         02          01-MAR-2013
5     N02      1233         02          01-MAR-2013
6     N02      1244         02          01-JUN-2013
```

I tried this query:

```
UPDATE np as updated_np 
SET invoice_no = old_np.invoice_no 
FROM np as old_np 
WHERE old_np.nameid = updated_np.nameid and 
      old_np.date = updated_np.date and 
      old_np.BILLEE_NO = updated_np.BILLEE_NO and 
      old_np.invoice_no != 'unallocated' and
      updated_np.invoice_no='unallocated';
```

Comment: Can you also please share with us what you have tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: I tried this one:UPDATE np as updated_np SET invoice_no = old_np.invoice_no
FROM np as old_np
WHERE old_np.nameid = updated_np.nameid and
old_np.date = updated_np.date and
old_np.BILLEE_NO = updated_np.BILLEE_NO and old_np.invoice_no != 'unallocated' and updated_np.invoice_no='unallocated';

Answer (score 0):

You can join on the same table using the NameID (+ the other columns) and specifying in the join clause to only join on a dataset which already has an allocated InvoiceNo.

```
UPDATE myTable
INNER JOIN myTable AS upd 
    ON upd.NameID = myTable.NameID 
    AND upd.BilleeNo = myTable.BilleeNo 
    AND upd.Date = myTable.Date 
    AND upd.InvoiceNo != "unallocated"
SET 
    myTable.InvoiceNo = upd.InvoiceNo
WHERE 
    myTable.InvoiceNo = "unallocated"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
update mytable set InvoiceNo='1233' where id in (select tb1.id from mytable tb1, mytable tb2 where tb1.InvoiceNumber='unallocated' and tb1.NameId=tb2.NameId and tb1.BilleNo=tb2.BilleNo and tb1.Date=tb2.Date)
```